# Is there a way to make an area inside <map> highlight upon hovering without using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: html, css

So i've been working on a uni assignment, the professor like my idea but asked if it was possible to make clickable areas on a map highlight or animate upon hovering, and my only options are CSS and HTML.

here's code for one of the pages:

```
    <head>
        <title>
        wizard forest
        </title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor = "#ffcc66" align="center">
        <p>
            <img src="img/wizard/area.png" usemap="#area">
        </p>
        <map name="area">
        <area shape="poly" href="wizard.html" coords="227,126,226,128,220,146,213,164,199,188,184,211,184,212,185,212,189,214,194,217,194,220,194,223,191,299,188,375,188,376,189,376,206,380,224,384,244,380,264,377,267,373,269,370,267,295,265,220,268,218,270,216,272,215,273,214,265,201,257,189,260,186,262,183,265,173,267,164,265,162,263,160,262,160,262,160,259,163,257,167,257,172,256,178,254,179,252,180,251,178,251,176,244,162,238,149,234,140,231,131,230,127,228,124">
        <area shape="poly" href="map.html" coords="58,64,56,66,56,72,56,78,48,85,40,93,40,94,40,96,48,104,56,112,56,117,56,122,58,124,60,126,126,126,192,126,194,124,196,121,196,93,196,65,194,63,191,61,125,61,60,61">
        </map>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp maybe this will help

Comment: Looking at the [mdn `<area>` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area) and inspecting an `<area>` they don't seem to actually take up any area on the screen (report as dimensions of 0x0), so it seems unlikely.  You may be better served by floating absolutely-positioned anchors with CSS over an image.